# What is a color matrix for adjusting luminance?

Tags: c#, objective-c, image-processing, image-manipulation

Searching around there is lots of information on converting an image to luminance (B&W) or adjusting saturation w/out changing luminance.  But how can you modify luminance itself?  For instance, how can I increase the red channel luminance using a 5x5 matrix?  Ultimately this will be used in C but the same math should work w/java or flash.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who came here from google, here is the matrix to scale luminance:

```
rl×l + gl + bl    gl×l - gl         bl×l - bl         0
rl×l - rl         gl×l + rl + bl    bl×l - bl         0
rl×l - rl         gl×l - gl         bl×l + rl + gl    0
0                 0                 0                 1
```

where

- `l` — luminance multiplier,
- `rl` — red luminance (0.213 for sRGB),
- `gl` — green luminance (0.715 for sRGB),
- `bl` — blue luminance (0.072 for sRGB).

**Please note:** this matrix may easily produce out of gamut colors, so don’t use it when you expect accurate results. For example, for the `1, 0, 0, 1` vector and `l=2` it will produce the `1.213, 0.213, 0.213, 1` result. Technically, this vector has the expected luminance (0.426), but the displayed color will be ≈0.381.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you change all three color values equally so...

To scale RGB colors a matrix like this is used:

```
float mat[4][4] = {
    rscale, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
    0.0,    gscale, 0.0,    0.0,
    0.0,    0.0,    bscale, 0.0,
    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,
};
```

From: http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html

Comment: Right, sorry I should have explained.  I have color matrix manipulation working for brightness, saturation, hue, shifts and colorizing.  I just can't figure out how to make one work for luminance.

Comment: Oh also the above matrix is for adjusting brightness, which is similar to luminance, but not quite :)